# What does `lib` mean in the config.gem call in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I see a command in `environment.rb` that says

```
config.gem 'thoughtbot-paperclip', :lib => 'paperclip', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

If I wanted to manually do it, it would be

```
gem install thoughtbot-papperclip --source http://gems.github.com
```

Where does the `lib` fit in to the command line gem call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `:lib` in your `environment.rb` if the library name is different with the gem name.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip doesn't need a library call.

```
gem.config 'paperclip'
```

that should take care of paperclip.

Some gems have crazy dependencies like syntax highlighting and they need to reference a library to meet the dependencies.